# How to ensure that docker is used only for my task

Tags: docker, protractor, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have an automation written using protractor.

I want to run it via jenkins.

My shell command:

```
docker pull selenium/hub:latest
docker pull selenium/node-chrome:latest
docker rm -f selenium-hub && echo "container selenium-hub removed" || echo "container selenium-hub does not exist"
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --name selenium-hub selenium/hub:latest
docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome:latest
protractor conf.js
```

Everything works perfectly.

My question is: Can i be absolutely sure that only my code is running on docker and all other component (like i have angular website running on same server) would not use the docker ie what precautions should i take while using docker if my server have 100s of different application running and i want that those applications should not have any side effect. Like if some app is running on nodejs v3 and my docker have nodejs v5, then application which were using nodejs v3 continue to run on nodejs v3 only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are worried that some other app is using selenium?  This is technically possible as when you started the selenium hub image the argument `-p 4444:4444` will bind the port 4444 to your localhost.

To make sure everything is self contained you would need to use the argument `-p 4444` and also run the protractor tests in a docker container.

A `Dockerfile` like this will do for your tests (untested)

```
FROM node:alpine

COPY your/source/directory /opt/

WORKDIR /opt/

RUN npm install -g protractor

CMD protractor conf.js
```

*NOTE*: Your protractor config will have to reference the selenium hub container name (i.e. selenium-hub) *not* localhost

Comment: So, if other applications are not linked with port 4444, then they would never use selenium. Right?

Comment: The docker containers will be in their own network.  The only way you can access them is to bind that network to your local one.  which is what `-p 4444:4444` does.  Your protractor conf probably references localhost:4444 in it's config to contact selenium.  If you are happy that none of your other apps are going to access localhost:4444 then you don't have to worry :)